# How to give applications (not users itself) permission to folder and files

Tags: python, security, permissions, windows-10

Is it possible to give an application read and write permissions to folder and files during its work without giving users which use the application these permission?

i write a software in python which is working with some files. I want to ensure that these files only can manipulate by the software. So my thougt was to create a folder without read an write rights and allowing only the application to read and write in this folder.
Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know about permissions much, but if a user doesn't have permissions but wants to delete all the data in his admin's PC, can't he just create a program to grant itself the necessary permissions and delete it if he can't manually?

Comment: No. what i mean was to create a folder without userrights but anywhere in the settings give just the application rights to read and write. Like no user have permission, but if users use the application, they can read and write

Comment: That's what, when the user is not meant to have or grant programs rights/permissions-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure if this helps bit what i would try and do is is set the application to create a local service account first with admin rights then when the application relaunches set it to run run as that service account then any folders created will be via that service account and therefore you can create a folder, modify its permissions to only be managed by that service account, brief steps below

1. application launches and checks if the service account exists if not then create the service account and assign to relevant admin group, once complete re-launch as that service account
2. once launched create the relevant directory
3. modify the directory's settings so all users are removed exp the service account

I think the above might work, good luck!

Comment: or as an alternative set the folders and files to be hidden and placed somewhere deep in the folder structure of the OS so the user wont see them or know where to look for them

Comment: That always won't work, even if you store it inside 100 folders ;) I'll use an autoclicker to open all of them :P

Comment: It's not about sensitive data and i dont think that anyone who use the software will try to manipulate these data outside the software. But this is a point i'm thinking of. The suggestion to hide the data is good and i'm sure that is enough but as a coder i'm thinking about a little more safety. The suggestion about to create a local service is good to but i think i need adminrights by myself to do this but for the computer where the software will launched i dont have or get adminrights. Not easy, i know. But thank to all for your advices. If someone knows another way to do this, let me know.

Comment: if you don't have admin rights to the machine it won't be possible to do what you are suggesting not on a windows pc as far as I know, permissions can only be managed by folder owners or admins that can override the user permissions, your other alternative is to think about the file format you're working with and depeding on the format you can encrypt the files so the user can't do much with them, or encrypt and hide

Comment: This is definitely an option. Thank you